# What does that exception mean in C#?

Tags: c#, ado.net

[image: exception]

What does this exception mean?

> 'System.EntryPointNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Unable to find an entry point named 'EventSetInformation' in DLL 'advapi32.dll'.

Answer (score 3):

It means you're trying to use the [`EventSetInformation` WinAPI function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh447256.aspx), which is available since Windows 8 (see the *Requirements* section of the linked MSDN doc).

Your screenshot shows you're on Windows 7, so the function is simply not there.

Comment: Is there a replacement on  Windows 7